# Codeigniter validation turns query row into array

Tags: arrays, validation, codeigniter

I recently experienced a very strange error. I am writing a password reset function but i am experiencing a very strange error i have never experienced before. Somehow, form validation turns my query into empty array.

Here is my code:

```
public function password_reset()
{
    if ($this->auth_model->is_logged_in()) redirect ('welcome');

        $userid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $code = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $this->db->select('forgot_password, id');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $this->db->where('id',$userid);
        $q = $this->db->get();

    if (!is_numeric($this->uri->segment(4, 0)) == TRUE && !is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3, 0)) == TRUE) die;

        if ($q->row('forgot_password') == $code) {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm', 'required|min_length[4]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() !== false) {

                if ($this->input->post('password') != $this->input->post('confirm_password')) exit("wrong");

                $update = array (
                    'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password'))
                );

                $id = $q->row('id');

                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->update('users', $update);
                echo $this->db->last_query();
                die; // Don't mind the last 2 lines, they were made for debugging purposes.

                echo "Password is reset";

            } $this->load->view('auth/password_reset');

        }

}
```

Please note this line:
$id = $q->row('id');

This is where the problem begins.

If i echo this line, will get "Array", i tried doing print_r on it but it appears to be completely empty array.

However, if i try echoing

```
$q->row('id');
```

before

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() !== false) {
```

then, i get what is expected, in my case it will be integer, but again, once form validation will be passed, it will turn my integer into empty array.

So here we are, form validation somehow turns my query row into an array.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are using this:

```
$q = $this->db->get();
//...
if ($q->row('forgot_password') == $code) {
```

You should fetch the object using `row()` only once, and then reference the properties of that object, rather than call `row()` over and over.

So, to get you on track to fixing this (there may be other issues with your code but we won't know until getting past this issue), try something like this:

```
$row = $this->db->get()->row();
```

That fetches the result (the first row). Done, now you have the result stored in an object and you don't need to fetch it again.

Now, when you want to reference a property of that object, the value of the column in this case, you would use this:

```
if ($row->forgot_password == $code) {}
//
$id = $row->id;
```

And so on. Have another read through the docs for more demos: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seems to work as planned.
Whenever i am using $row->columnname; i get error:

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

And therefore value is returned as NULL.

Comment: So, `$this->db->get()->row()->id;` gives you `NULL`? Hmm, I forget what the return value is if a row isn't found, but perhaps you simply did not find a match for `where('id', $userid)`? Either way, the code you are currently using is not the correct syntax. Try stepping through it with some `exit(var_dump($var))`s and make sure each variable contains what you expect.

Comment: I think i figured out what the problem is in but not how to fix it.
Because i am using URL segments, once form passes validation, it loses these segments which causes the errors to appear.

Comment: Found this. - http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/195567/#920563
I think will have to rebuild code a little so the edit function will be in different function.

Anyway, thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Is your form's `action` attribute correct? There's no other explanation why you would "lose" URI segments if you were able to access them before, unless the url changed.

Comment: It is correct. It just appears that form validation have to be in a separate function. See link above.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `result_array()` and check the first records against the parameter...

```
$q = $this->db->select('forgot_password, id')
              ->from('users')
              ->limit(1)
              ->where('id',$userid)
              ->get();
$res = $q->result_array();
$forgot_password = (count($res[0]) == 1) $res[0]['forgot_password'] : FALSE;
...
// And change this line
// if ($q->row('forgot_password') == $code) {
// into
if ( ! $forgot_password)
{
   // Theres no record match with $userid
}
elseif($forgot_password == $code)
{
   // Everythings fine...
}
else
{
   // Theres a record match with $userid, but the $code not match
}
```